# Responsive stripes in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid in BS3 which can have either 4, 2 or 1 columns depnding on device size. It is striped for the 4 max column width.

```
<div class="row row-odd">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row row-even">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>

.row-even {
  background-color: #B2D6B2;
}
.row-odd {
  background-color: #D8ECC3;
}
```

this works ok but I would ideally like it to be striped responsively and actually looks stiped.

The first 4 cells are the same colour. I want only the first 2 or the first 1 cell to be the same colour depending on the resolution so it looks striped to the user.

So in 4 column mode I want colour 1 (C1) and 2 (C2) as follows

C1C1C1C1C2C2C2C2C1C1C1C1C2C2C2C2 (i.e. blocks of 4)

and in 2 column mode

C1C1C2C2C1C1C2C2  (i.e. blocks of 2)

and 1 column mode

C1C2C1C2C1C2C1C2  (i.e. blocks of 1)

how can I do this?

I have a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GrimRob/1cj2e828/3/

Comment: Could you make your question a little bit more clear? I am personally getting lost in the `C1C1C1C1C2C2C2C2C1C1C1C1C2C2C2C2`. Does `C1` represent a column, or does `C1C1C1C1` represent a column?

Comment: C1 and C2 are colours. The first 4 cells are the same colour. I want only the first 2 or the first 1 cell to be the same colour depending on the resolution so it looks striped.